# java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Tags: java

I want to get the records from database but got an error : [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to beans.Book

The DAO Class have the following code:

```
List<Book> studentList=new BooksDAO().searchBook(cmbBookType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Iterator<Book> it = studentList.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Inside While_btnSearch ");
            System.out.println(it.next());
            Book book = (Book)it.next();
            System.out.println("Iterator converted to book ");
            for(int i=0;i<studentList.size();i++){
                    bookTable.setValueAt(book.getCode(), i, 0);
                    bookTable.setValueAt(book.getName(), i, 1); 
                    bookTable.setValueAt(book.getAuthor(), i, 2);
                    bookTable.setValueAt(book.getPublisher(), i, 3);
                    bookTable.setValueAt(book.getIsbn(), i, 4);
            }
```

and the error log messages are here:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to beans.Book
at lms.SearchBook.btnSearchActionPerformed(SearchBook.java:286)
at lms.SearchBook.access$200(SearchBook.java:19)
at lms.SearchBook$4.actionPerformed(SearchBook.java:126)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
```

The searchBook() is as follows---

```
public List<Book> searchBook(String b_type){
    Query qr;
    Session session=SessionFact.getSessionFact().openSession();   
    qr=session.createQuery("select b.code,b.name,b.author,b.publisher,b.isbn from Book b where b.type=:bookType");
    qr.setParameter("bookType", b_type);
    System.out.println("Book Search Completed ");
    List<Book> booklist=qr.list();
    session.close();
    return booklist;

}
```

Please Help Me..

Comment: What is the return type of the `searchBook` method?

Comment: "Please solve my problem and give a suitable code." **No. We do not solve all of your problems for you.** *Why should we?* Instead, we will help debug your program and solve your issue - but only if you supply us with enough information and do some research yourself first - what have you tried, what has worked, what hasn't, etc. Please read more on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The error message means that you have an `Object[]` (an array of objects), which you are trying to cast to `beans.Book`. That won't work, an `Object[]` is not a `beans.Book`. Another issue: Why does your `searchBook` method return a raw `List` instead of a `List<Book>`?

Answer (score 0):

This mean the object you are trying to cast as book isn't a book instance, try debugging or check is instanceof  before casting to confirm.